# Rails 5.2.4.3でAjaxの実装ができない

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax

下記のページをそれぞれ参考にRails 5.2.4.3でのAjaxの実装を試みていますが、
ログをみるとHTMLになっており反応していなさそうです。

**参考にしたページ**
[【Rails】remote: trueでサクッと画面切り替え](http://song-of-life.hatenablog.com/entry/2017/09/30/234356) 
[form_forをremote: trueでAjax実装](https://kurose.me/form_for_ajax/)
[【Rails初心者】Ajaxの実装方法を理解する(非同期通信) - Qiita](https://qiita.com/rio_threehouse/items/b067d64eafdfbd25b91d)

どの記事をみても、まずは `form_with` などに `remote: true` を加える必要があるそうなのですが動きません。動かないというよりはボタンをクリックしてもHTML遷移してしまいます。
これはどのようなことが原因と考えられるでしょうか？

```
<div id="samplRemote">
<%= form_with(model: @hashtag, url: users_path, method: :get, local: true, remote: true) do |f| %>
        <%= f.submit 'RandomTag', class: 'btn btn-primary btn-sm' %>    
        <!--<div>-->
            <button class="clipboard-btn" data-clipboard-action="copy" data-clipboard-target="#bar">
                Copy
            </button>
        <!--</div>-->

        <%= f.label :"Set Number" %>
        <%= f.select :hashtags, 1.upto(30).map{|i| [i, i]}, class:"form-control" %><br>
<% end %>
```

追記
ありがとうございます。
確かにlocal: trueを削除するとJSに切り替わったようです。
ですがボタンクリックしても作動しません。
これはコントローラー側のコードが悪いのでしょうか？
ここを参考にしながら書きました。
https://www.sejuku.net/blog/28967
http://song-of-life.hatenablog.com/entry/2017/09/30/234356

UsersController

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
  before_action :require_user_logged_in, only: [:index, :show]

  def index
    if logged_in?
      @hashtag = current_user.hashtags.build  # form_with 用
      @hashtags = current_user.hashtags.order(id: :desc).page(params[:page])
      if params[:hashtag].nil?
        @randomtags = Hashtag.order("RAND()").limit(28)
        # Ajax
          respond_to do |format|
            format.html
            format.js
          end
        # Ajax
      else
        @randomtags = Hashtag.order("RAND()").limit(params[:hashtag][:hashtags])
        # Ajax
          respond_to do |format|
            format.html
            format.js
          end
        # Ajax
      end
    end
  end
```

ビューファイルです。
パーシャルへレンダーしています。
index.js.erb

```
$('#samplRemote').html("<%= escape_javascript(render 'randomtags') %>");
```

index.html.erb

```
<div id="samplRemote">
        <%= form_with(model: @hashtag, url: users_path, method: :get, remote: true) do |f| %>
                <%= f.submit 'RandomTag', class: 'btn1 btn-primary btn-sm' %>    
                <!--<div>-->
                    <button class="clipboard-btn btn1 btn-primary btn-sm" data-clipboard-action="copy" data-clipboard-target="#bar">
                        Copy
                    </button>
                <!--</div>-->
                <div class = "setnumber">
                <%= f.label :"Set Number" %>
                </div>
                <%= f.select :hashtags, 1.upto(30).map{|i| [i, i]}, class:"form-control" %><br>
        <% end %>

                <!-- Target -->
                <div class="box2" id="bar">
                    <p><%= render 'randomtags/randomtags', randomtags: @randomtags %></p>
                </div>
                <!-- Trigger -->
</div>
```

Comment: `form_with`の`local: true`を外すとどうなりますか？　`local: true`があると通常のフォーム送信になるようです。また、参考のページは`form_for`や`form_tag`の場合のようです。あと、`form_with`は`remote`オプションがなく、デフォルトがAjaxのようです。参考：https://techracho.bpsinc.jp/hachi8833/2017_05_01/39502 と https://qiita.com/peco4107/items/f03580f6eeb12eb7ac41 のメモ部分

Comment: ありがとうございます。確かにlocal: trueを削除するとJSに切り替わったようです。ですがまだ作動しないようです。おそらく私のコントローラー側の記載がおかしいのかもしれません。一度お時間ある時にでも追記分をご覧いただけますと幸いです。

Comment: jQueryを使っているようですが、使用するように設定しているでしょうか？　Rails 5.2からはデフォルトではjQueryは含まれないので、使用する場合は設定を追加する必要があります。参考：https://qiita.com/Masato338/items/911218d67cd052d874fd （ちなみに、`ready`や`turbolinks:load`で動かす処理は今のところなさそうなので、3は追加不要と思われます）

Comment: 下記に従い行ったところ、なんとか実装できました。ありがとうございます。https://github.com/sadiqmmm/clipboard-rails